Apple TV 2nd Generation Siri Remote not Detecting Fast Forward/Backward
I'm using AVPlayer on Apple TV 2nd generation which has that siri click pad with four buttons around and we need to detect where the user clicked on the Siri remote fast forward/backward. I have tested many different approaches to do it, but nothing is working for me.
Does anyone have any idea how to resolve it in Swift?
